# How to use HTML in a CSS-only tooltip

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS-only tooltip that uses a special element attribute to provide the content:

```
<li class="privTooltip" data-tooltip="My tooltip text">
```

Which is then handled in CSS:

```
<style>
  [data-tooltip]:after {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
   ...styling...
   }
</style>
```

But this only supports raw text. If I try to provide any HTML tags, like `data-tooltip="<b>Granted through role paths</b>...more stuff"`, they aren't interpreted:

[image]

Text decoration, maybe a simple HTML table, etc.. would make these a lot nicer. I know I can write a DOM-based tooltip that does just about anything, but I'd like to know if it's possible with this lighter-weight pseudo-element CSS-only method.

Comment: You can't get html from a stylesheet to appear rendered on the page in any way, unfortunately (not even when read from a DOM property). If you want to do this without writing the tooltip elements into your HTML document, then doing it dynamically with JavaScript is probably the only way.

Comment: Thanks, that's kinda what I figured. Was worth an ask anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't use your exact method, but it is CSS-only, which it sounds like is the important part for your use-case. You could try something like this, which allows you to style the tooltip's content with CSS.

EDIT: [here's a live version of this in CodePen](https://codepen.io/tylerwoodcook/pen/RwBPoee)

#### HTML

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <!-- put the content you want to hover over here -->
  <img style="width: 40px; padding: 16px;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e4/Infobox_info_icon.svg/1200px-Infobox_info_icon.svg.png">

  <span class="tooltiptext">
    <!-- put the tooltip here -->
    <strong>Title 1:</strong> Lorem ipsum.<br><br>
    <strong>Title 2:</strong> Lorem ipsum.<br><br>
    <strong>Title 3:</strong> Lorem ipsum.<br><br>
    <strong>Title 4:</strong> Lorem ipsum.
  </span>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  padding: 8px;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to see if this can be done without constructing a DOM-based tooltip like this. I like the ease of just adding a single tooltip-data attribute to any element I want to tooltip-enable it, but it's hard to believe that CSS's content: attribute is so primitive.